# How can I make a RAID 0 partition with USB drives?

Tags: 18.04, usb, raid

I have 2  old 256MB USB 2.0 drives that I would like to configure them as a RAID 0 on Ubuntu 18.04

How can I do that?

First USB stick: Corsair Flash Voyager 256MB 
Second USB stick: Twinmos Mobile Disk IV 256MB

Comment: RAID 0 fails if either drive fails an loses all data in the RAID. Since USB flash drives have a much higher failure rate, _especially if they are old as you noted_,  than HDDs and SSDs, making a RAID with flash drives is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
How about RAID 1 instead?

Comment: Then take a look at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mdadm.8.html  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120874/how-to-setup-a-raid-system-using-usb-sticks-as-storage-media